# how to use google place api for my php application

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a web page. When user starts typing in a textbox, an autocomplete city with state name list appears in suggested dropdown box like in google map.

I've got the api for google place autocomplete. But I am unable to implement it.

**Can any one suggest me how to implement google place api?**

API URL is: [Google Place API Page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#place_autocomplete_requests)

Comment: You need to use AJAX. Read example jquery: http://jquery.com

Comment: I quite good in ajax request. But can you give me briefing where to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What i implemented is the below code and it gave me the solution that i wanted -

```
   <html>
       <head>
       <style type="text/css">
               body {
                       font-family: sans-serif;
                       font-size: 14px;
               }
       </style>
       <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
       <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
               function initialize() {
                       var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
                       var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
               }
               google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
       </script>
       </head>
           <body>
               <div>
                       <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
               </div>
           </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jquery plugin

http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/

demo:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html

Comment: I've already visited this link before posting this question and based on that i investigated further. Still not able to reproduce the same thing on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the link, and do a CTRL + U, it gives you the source, then SELECT ALL, then PASTE IT, and it works.

Comment: what are you suggesting? I didn't understand correctly. Anyway i got the solution and have also accepted it as you can see.